# API call to query historical data in Yodlee

Tags: yodlee

Can anyone with experience using the Yodlee Aggregation API point me to the API call used to query historical data (such as bank balance for last 90 days, etc)?

Does Yodlee Aggregation API provide/collect/have access to such historical data in general? 
I wasnt able to find anything in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no API available to provide account balances for last 90 days. Yodlee provide the latest balance of the account. But you can get transactional details for last 90 days.